# R Shiny | evaluating user textInput with dynamic UI

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, rlang

I want to safely allow my app users to be able to manipulate the dataset in my shiny app - by passing code to a data %>% mutate (input$textInput1), and then updating a reactive value containing the manipulated data, `v$data`.

There are answers for how to use a single, pre-named input and parse it, but I can't extrapolate to how to define this for several text inputs.
e.g. 'input$textinput1','input$textinput2'..

Pressing the recode button with an activated input field causes the error:

> `` Warning: Error in : Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`. x <text>:1:1: unexpected '[[' 1: [[ ^ ℹ Input `..1` is `eval.secure(parse(text = paste0("[[input$recode_call", >i, "]]")))`. 94: <Anonymous> ``

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(colourpicker)
library(RAppArmor)


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

  #Tracks user changes to input
  v <- reactiveValues(data=NULL, print_execute_complete=NULL)

  #For development, mtcars
  myData <- reactive({
    return(mtcars)
  })

  #Count the number of recoding terms to render
  counter <- reactiveValues(n = 0)

  observeEvent(input$add_recode, {counter$n <-  counter$n + 1})
  observeEvent(input$rm_recode, {
    if(counter$n > 0) counter$n <-  counter$n - 1
  })


  #Recoding button functionality
  recoding_i <- reactive({

    n <- counter$n

    if(n>0){
      isolate({
        lapply(seq_len(n),function(i){

          fluidRow(
            column(width=4,
                   textInput(inputId = paste0('recode_call',i),
                             label=paste0('Recode_',i)))
          )
        }
        )

      })
    }
  })

  #Render the dynamic UI
  output$recoding <- renderUI({ recoding_i() })

  #Observes press of recode button.
  observeEvent(input$'execute_recode',{
    v[["print_execute_complete"]] <- TRUE
  })

  #Observes press of reset button.
  observeEvent(input$'reset_recode',{
    v[["print_execute_complete"]] <- FALSE
  })


  #Loop over recoding input boxes.
  observeEvent(v$print_execute_complete, {
    if(v[["print_execute_complete"]] == TRUE){
      if(counter$n==0|is.null(counter$n)){
        return(myData())
      } else {
        lapply(seq_len(counter$n), function(i){
          if(is.null((v[["data"]]))){
            v$data <- myData() %>% mutate(eval.secure(parse(text=paste0('[[input$recode_call',i,']]'))))
          } else {
            v$data <- v[["data"]] %>%  mutate(eval.secure(parse(text=paste0('[[input$recode_call',i,']]'))))
          }
        }
        )
      }
    }
  })






  #Confirmation text
  output$execute_complete <- renderText({
    req(v[["print_execute_complete"]])
    if(v[["print_execute_complete"]] == TRUE){
      "Recoding Complete."
    }

  })

  #Render recoded data table
  output$recoded_dt <- DT::renderDataTable({
    req(v[["print_execute_complete"]] == TRUE)
    if(!is.null(v[["data"]])){
      return(DT::datatable(v[["data"]], filter='top'))

    } else {
      return(iris)#DT::datatable(myData(),filter='top'))
    }
  })

}
)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(


  titlePanel("Something is Wrong"),
  # Input: Select a file ----
  navlistPanel(
    tabPanel("Recoding",

             h3("Instruction"),

             fluidRow(p("Write a functional call in one of the action boxes below. A call takes the form of one of the following :"
                        ,style="font-family: 'times'; font-si16pt")
             ),

             fluidRow(actionButton('add_recode', 'Add recode term'),
                      actionButton('rm_recode', 'Remove recode term')),
             br(),
             br(),
             uiOutput('recoding'),
             br(),
             br(),
             fluidRow(actionButton('execute_recode', "Recode",icon = icon('angle-double-right')),
                      actionButton('reset_recode', "Reset", icon=icon('angle-double-right'))),
             textOutput('execute_complete'),
             br(),
             br(),
             br(),
             DT::dataTableOutput('recoded_dt')

    )
  )
)
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I suggest you first try to solve this outside of `shiny`: define a structure `input <- list(recode_call = "something your users can do")` and figure out how to get it to work in `mutate`. I suspect you'll need some meta-programming, look into `rlang` and `tidyeval` vignettes.

Comment: This might be a good use case for [shinyAce](https://github.com/trestletech/shinyAce).

Comment: @r2evans it took a day or two of work, but I have uploaded code that I managed to put together. Could anyone improve upon my answer / explanation of how tidyeval / rlang handles my call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code captures a dynamic number of textInputs and converts them to code matching: 'Variable name' 'Code call'. These must be handled separately by rlang evaluation since anything left of := must be a symbol. The chain of functions transform a textInput to actionable code.

I have *tried* to understand why this works (edits welcome by those who understand rlang/tidyeval!):

> For each of the additional textInput boxes created, a counter allows an anonymous function to loop over and create and paste together valid input name, e.g. input$recode_call1. This is then evaluated as text, parsed into an expression, where it is evaluated and interpreted, and then turned into an expression.

Unanswered questions about this answer:

- Error possibilities. Can certain inputs create bugs?
- Security concerns. Can / should `rlang::eval_tidy()` be swapped out for, e.g. `unix::eval.safe()`?
- Is there an easier / more secure way to handle the dynamic input?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(colourpicker)
library(RAppArmor)


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

  #Tracks user changes to input
  v <- reactiveValues(data=NULL, print_execute_complete=NULL)

  #For development, mtcars
  myData <- reactive({
    return(mtcars)
  })

  #Count the number of recoding terms to render
  counter <- reactiveValues(n = 0)

  observeEvent(input$add_recode, {counter$n <-  counter$n + 1})
  observeEvent(input$rm_recode, {
    if(counter$n > 0) counter$n <-  counter$n - 1
  })


  #Recoding button functionality
  recoding_i <- reactive({

    n <- counter$n

    if(n>0){
      isolate({
        lapply(seq_len(n),function(i){

          fluidRow(
            column(width=4,
                   textInput(inputId = paste0('recode_call',i),
                             label=paste0('Recode_',i)))
          )
        }
        )

      })
    }
  })

  #Render the dynamic UI
  output$recoding <- renderUI({ recoding_i() })

  #Observes press of recode button.
  observeEvent(input$'execute_recode',{
    v[["print_execute_complete"]] <- TRUE
  })

  #Observes press of reset button.
  observeEvent(input$'reset_recode',{
    v[["print_execute_complete"]] <- FALSE
  })


   #Loop over recoding input boxes.
    observeEvent(v$print_execute_complete, {
      if(v[["print_execute_complete"]] == TRUE){
        n <- counter$n
        if(counter$n==0){
          v$data <- myData()
         } else {
           v$data <- myData()
           lapply(seq_len(n), function(i){
             recode_call_i <- rlang::parse_expr(rlang::eval_tidy(rlang::parse_expr(eval(paste0("input$recode_call",i)))))

             var_name_i <- rlang::sym(rlang::eval_tidy(rlang::parse_expr(paste0("input$recode_name",i))))

             v$data <- mutate(v$data,!!var_name_i := !!recode_call_i)
           }
           )
             }
      }
    }
    )






  #Confirmation text
  output$execute_complete <- renderText({
    req(v[["print_execute_complete"]])
    if(v[["print_execute_complete"]] == TRUE){
      "Recoding Complete."
    }

  })

  #Render recoded data table
  output$recoded_dt <- DT::renderDataTable({
    req(v[["print_execute_complete"]] == TRUE)
    if(!is.null(v[["data"]])){
      return(DT::datatable(v[["data"]], filter='top'))

    } else {
      return(iris)#DT::datatable(myData(),filter='top'))
    }
  })

}
)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(


  titlePanel("This time it works"),
  # Input: Select a file ----
  navlistPanel(
    tabPanel("Recoding",

             h3("Instruction"),

             fluidRow(p("Write a functional call in one of the action boxes below. A call takes the form of one of the following :"
                        ,style="font-family: 'times'; font-si16pt")
             ),

             fluidRow(actionButton('add_recode', 'Add recode term'),
                      actionButton('rm_recode', 'Remove recode term')),
             br(),
             br(),
             uiOutput('recoding'),
             br(),
             br(),
             fluidRow(actionButton('execute_recode', "Recode",icon = icon('angle-double-right')),
                      actionButton('reset_recode', "Reset", icon=icon('angle-double-right'))),
             textOutput('execute_complete'),
             br(),
             br(),
             br(),
             DT::dataTableOutput('recoded_dt')

    )
  )
)
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```